# How to synchronize DynamoDB users data table with AWS Cognito for creating/updating/deleting users in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

So I am working on a web application in which I am performing signup by taking users data from web form and passing it on to a lambda function which stores it in a DynamoDB table. But now I also want to utilize the AWS Cognito authentication service. So the data I am storing in the DynamoDB also consists of the email address field.I want my application to perform the following flow of steps:

1. User Signups data including email address stored in DynamoDB via a lambda function.
2. Once data is stored in DynamoDB I want some sort of trigger which can take registered users email address from the DynamoDB and passes it AWS Cognito.
3. AWS Cognito creates a user account sends user a random password or a link where the user can set the password themselves.

The Signup and storing data onto DynamoDB is working for me but the part where synchronization needs to happen is confusing me. It would be highly appreciated if someone can guide me a bit here.

Comment: If you’re able to change the registration flow, having the user register with Cognito first and then, when the account is confirmed, use the Cognito post confirmation lambda trigger to put the data to Dynamo, might be an easier/better pattern to implement. Otherwise, take a look at DynamoDB streams which a Lambda can consume and use the CognitoAPI to register the user etc.

Comment: @hephalump exactly right...If you can use cognito triggers, your life will be much simpler.